# php while loop runs in shell but not on the browser

Tags: php

I have made a very simple PHP7 page that shows the values of temperature sensors in a table. I extract this data from a MySQL database. The PHP7 is running with apache2 on a raspberrypi 3.

This all works well and I am able to get the code to run on the CLI and it generates HTML just fine. But when I run the page in the browser it only shows what comes before and after the while loop. All the other PHP/HTML shows fine. the file name is `tempsense.php`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        TEMP 
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
    <?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","*********");
        $db = mysqli_select_db($con,"connected_sensors");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM sensors";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        echo "<table border='1'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Sensor ID</th><th>Sensor Name</th><th>Temp F</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>", $row['sensor_id'], "</td><td>", $row['sensor_name'], "</td><td>", $row['sensor_value'], "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
</body>
```

The source from the browser is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        TEMP
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
    <table border='1'><tr><th>Sensor ID</th><th>Sensor Name</th><th>Temp F</th></tr></table>    </body>
```

and from the PHP CLI

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        TEMP
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
    <table border='1'><tr><th>Sensor ID</th><th>Sensor Name</th><th>Temp F</th></tr><tr><td>28-0517c15db7ff</td><td>Device_0</td><td>79.5866</td></tr><tr><td>28-0117b3e303ff</td><td>Device_1</td><td>79.1366</td></tr></table>    </body>
```

I know this is probably dumb but I'm loosing my mind. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the HTML in the browser. Is it spitting out nothing there? Or raw PHP code?

Comment: i posted the source from the browser. it just shows the head of the table and nothing else

Comment: Check for errors; check the values of `mysqli_connect_error()` and `mysqli_error($con)`. Also check your error logs.

Comment: ok i have found the issue. I got access denied at mysql because i have been root this whole time out of laziness. I am resolving it now.

TL;DR root is evil and I should not have been using it in the process.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out! And yes, good call on using another account!